# JavaScript - disable submit button

Tags: javascript, submit, getelementbyid

My function isn't able to disable the submit button (id="mySubmit"), the rest works fine. (The function is called on "onkeyup")

I am trying to disable it if the values of the two password fields do not match.

```js
function check_match() {

    var pw1 = document.getElementById("one").value;
    var pw2 = document.getElementById("two").value;

    if (pw1 == pw2) {
        document.getElementById("error_match").style.color = "green";
        document.getElementById("error_match").innerHTML = "paswords match";
        document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("error_match").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("error_match").innerHTML = "passwords do not match";
        document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = true;
    }

}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="userregister" method="POST">

    <label for="email"><b>E-Mail</b></label>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter E-Mail" name="email" required />

    <!--Password1-->
    <label for="password"><b>Passwort</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="one" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" onkeyup="check_match();" required />
    <span id="error"></span>

    <!--Password2-->
    <label for="password2"><b>repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password again" name="password2" id="two" onkeyup="check_match();" required />
    <span id="error_match"></span><br />

    <input type="checkbox" id="conditionbox" onclick="conditioncheck()" checked required>
    <a href="conditions.php" style="text-decoration: none">conditions </a>accepted<br />
    <span id="message" class="agberror"></span>

    <button type="submit" id="mySubmit" name="reg">Register</button>

</form>
```

I put the script part at the end of the body tag

Comment: Your code is working accordingly.

Comment: I still can submit the form even if the values do not match

Comment: check the question which is edited now, there are no issues, it works as expected.

Comment: How can you submit when the button is disabled?

Comment: At most, you can compare with `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: Ahhh sorry haven't seen I can run the code snippet here. It just doesn't run on the xampp localhost. Probably the error is something else. But thank you for your answers. :)

Comment: Just to let you know, I importetd the error via php from another form. I apologize for this dumb mistake.

Comment: your code is working

Answer (score 0):

You have just use === instead ==.

3 == '3' // true - because value is same
3 === '3' //false - because datatype is not same

always use === strict equal